# SQLite data types in version 4?

Tags: sqlite, .net-4.0

**I know there are a lot of places where I can find sqlite data types such as in [this link](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) or [this other link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388098/sqlite-data-types).**

**Maybe this question sounds stupid when I mention version 4 because version 4 documentation is not out there on the internet or maybe I have not been able to find it. Why is it that the dll library that I downloaded from SQLite site has:**

[image]

**also when I downloaded that library from [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) (sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.79.0.exe) and install the visual studio plugins I am able to create sqlite databases in visual studio as:**

[image]

### Note that I have several data types!!

**I am very confused on the versions of sqlite. Am I using sqlite version 3? What are the data types that I can use with the version that I downloaded from [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)? If I am using sqlite version 3, then why does the visual studio table designer for sqlite gives me different data types than the ones from the documentation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as there's no such thing as SQLite 4.x (yet, anyway), you're definitely using SQLite 3.7.10. The v4.0.30319 almost certainly refers to the .NET runtime, not SQLite.

SQLite has only a few built-in types, but ADO.NET has an interface to conform to, so this adapter does its best to map the set of types you see to SQLite's (much smaller) set of native types.